# Python/Kivy : add a calendar in kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to kivy/python.I want to add a `calendar` on textBox.
this code gives error `ImportError: No module named KivyCalendar`
Can someone tell me how to make it?
Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated..!!

## demo.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from KivyCalendar import CalendarWidget


class SetIndex(BoxLayout):
    def setDate(self, *args):
        popup = Popup(title='Insert Old Date', content=CalendarWidget(), size_hint=(.9, .5)).open()


class Demo(App):
    def bulid(self):
        return SetIndex()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Demo().run()
```

## demo.kv

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: 1, .4

    TextInput:
        id: old_date
        hint_text: "Old Date"
        on_focus: root.setDate()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the KivyCalendar is an extra module you can find here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/KivyCalendar and install with "python setup.py install" or on posix system just use "sudo -H pip install KivyCalendar" from a terminal prompt to get it downloaded, built and installed system wide.